# KVM/QEMU CentOS 8 kickstarted VMs have broken networking, are unreachable

Tags: kvm-virtualization, kickstart, centos8, virt-install

I can't understand why the VMs I create using virt-install & kickstart do not have networking that can be accessed reliably from foreign hosts. The VMs I created using virt-manager can be logged into using ssh, are pingable etc. but the kickstarted ones are inaccessible.

Even if I virsh edit the kickstarted VM and change  to  the change did not survive reboot.
kube2 was created using virt-install and kickstart. The other two were created with virt-manager.

```
[root@kraken msh]# virsh dumpxml kube2 |grep bridge
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='br0'/>

[root@kraken msh]# virsh dumpxml kube1 |grep bridge
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source network='host-bridge' bridge='br0'/>

[root@kraken msh]# virsh dumpxml kube0 |grep bridge
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source network='host-bridge' bridge='br0'/>
```

What syntax do I use in my virt-install script to make sure the source network (host-bridge) is built? My virt-install --network syntax has varied so much I don't even want to post it here. Sometimes I'm able to ssh to the IP of the VM but not the hostname.

Do I need "--bridge br0" in my virsh-install syntax or something else?

Comment: The VM's networking works from the VM to the Internet. I can 'dnf update' all day.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong DEVICE= name in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp2s0f1 which is NIC I enslaved to br0.

I executed

```
nmcli connection add type bridge-slave autoconnect yes con-name enp0s8 ifname enp0s8 master br0
```

instead of the correct

```
nmcli connection add type bridge-slave autoconnect yes con-name enp0s8 ifname enp2s0f1 master br0
```

So the problem was one of copy+pasta or pebkac. Had nothing to do with virt-install. Here's my working virt-install syntax.

```
virt-install \
        --name kube2 \
        --memory 8192 \
        --graphics none \
        --vcpus 2 \
        --disk path=/pool/libvirt/images/kube2.qcow2 \
        --network bridge=br0 -w network=host-bridge \
        --os-variant centos8 \
        --console pty,target_type=serial \
        --location http://192.168.10.2/centos8 \
        --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial' \
        -x "ks=http://192.168.10.2/kube-centos-8.cfg"
```

Comment: I don't (you don't) need to specify the network (-w network=host-bridge) if you have only one kvm network.